# How to define a custom keymap on Wayland with KDE?

Tags: customization, kde-plasma, keymapping, wayland

Well, I think everything is said on the title : How does one define a new custom keymap (Either by redefining the whole keymap, or by calling programs like xmodmap in a .bashrc-like ? ) on Kde (Plasma) on Wayland ?

Since each client receive a virtual keyboard, I'm guessing there is no way to define a keymap in wayland in general, am I right ?